# Converting "raw" request to JSON (Rest Services) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

Apologize in advance if my post doesn't make any sense. I have to create an API which calls a REST service URL (`POST`).

This is the sample payload:

```
{
  "request": {
    " TestRequest": {
      "OrderID": {
        "orderNumber": "12345",
        "category": "ABC"
      },
      "SecondCategory": "DEF"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I pass this in my API? I'm very new to this, so I have no idea. I tested this in Postman and it worked fine, but there I just had to paste this raw request as is. Do I have to convert it into `JSON`?

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably want to create types (classes) that follow the structure of that JSON. Then you can use the strong type as a parameter to your API action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to convert it into JSON?

Technically what you've posted here *is* JSON. JSON is simply a **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject serialized to a string (the `N` is for **N**otation).

When it comes to how to handle this in C#, there are a number of potential options.

If you've got only a couple of calls with small JSON payloads like this, you can just use basic C# string handling:

```
var orderNumber = "12345";
var category = "ABC";
var secondCategory = "DEF";
var JsonString =
    $"{{\"request\":{{\"TestRequest\":{{\"OrderID\":{{\"orderNumber\": \"{orderNumber}\",\"category\":\"{category}\"}},\"SecondCategory\":\"{secondCategory}\"}}}}}}";
```

While treating it like a string is pretty simple, it isn't very maintainable over time. Heck, I *wrote* that string and even I can't read it. ;)

A better option is to construct classes that match the structure of the JSON you want and then use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize them at runtime. Json.NET is an extremely robust and efficient JSON library.

To start, you need to define classes that match the structure of your JSON:

```
public class Root {
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

public class Request {
    public TestRequest TestRequest { get; set; }
}

public class TestRequest {
    public OrderID OrderID { get; set; }
    public string SecondCategory { get; set; }
}

public class OrderID {
    public string orderNumber { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use Json.NET to serialize these into a JSON string:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention the **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes** command in Visual Studio as a quick way to generate the classes?

Comment: I try to avoid including IDE features since so many developers have their own preferred environment (VS, VSCode, Atom, etc., etc.) but this is an **excellent** tip. It's one of my favorite shortcuts in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There's loads of ways!  Loads of client-side frameworks to connection type stuff for you, jQuery, SignalR, Atmosphere,..

Something to remember though is that data you're sending isn't the only data the receiver will probably need in order to handle your message.  It'll have "headers" which describe the message, and a "body" which will contain your data.

There are loads of examples out there, my personal favourite: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

To return to your question

> DO I have to convert it into JSON

Not really, but you'll have to convert it to something your server can understand.  Because it's going over the network, it'll need to be serialised, and specifying JSON as that serialisation method is very common.  Internally, I expect if it's not a string already the frameworks will be auto-serialising it for you however they want to.